# mongoimport apply the data type as string for all fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

When we import CSV file data `mongodimport` automatically choose data type for each field.

Is it possible to apply the data type as the string for all fields? the *--columnsHaveTypes* can help to define the field type. But I don't want to define each field and type manually.

Here is my schell script:

```
cd <path to direcotry of csv files>
$files = Get-ChildItem .
foreach ($f in $files) {
  if ($f -Like "*.csv") {
   mongoimport -d mydb -c mycollection --type csv --file $f --headerline
 }
}
```

Appreciate your help!